# Choosing the Right Visual Studio Template for a React Project with Entity Framework Backend

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm working on a React project that until now has utilized mock data, and I'm planning to integrate it with a real database using Entity Framework. I'm familiar with setting up Entity Framework, but I'm uncertain about the appropriate backend setup using C# in Visual Studio. Specifically, I'm contemplating whether to use the ASP.NET Core with React.js template, but I'm unsure if it aligns with my project requirements.

I aim to maintain my React application and the C# backend as potentially separate projects: the React app in Visual Studio Code and the C# backend handling HTTP requests in Visual Studio. However, I'm open to the idea of merging them into a single project if it proves to be a more efficient approach without significant additional effort.

Could you advise on whether it's better to keep these projects separate or to combine them? Additionally, which Visual Studio project template would be most suitable for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022) first,
Visual Studio 2022 supports a new **SPA template** for Javascript.
Now we can maintain javascript projects in solution.
So My preferred way is

1. [React Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-create-react-app?view=vs-2022)
2. [Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Check this [repository](https://github.com/andissanayake/UnifiedApp/tree/master/src), It follows the same implementation.

**Create a React app** instructions from msdn

**Prerequisites**
Make sure to install the following:

1. Visual Studio 2022 or later. Go to the Visual Studio downloads page to install it for free.
2. npm (https://www.npmjs.com/), which is included with Node.js
   npx (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx)

**Create your app**

3. In the Start window (choose File > Start Window to open), select Create a new project.
4. Search for React in the search bar at the top and then select Standalone JavaScript React Project or Standalone TypeScript React Project, based on your preference.
5. Give your project and solution a name.
6. If you previously selected Standalone JavaScript React Template, when you get to the Additional information window be sure NOT to check the Add integration for Empty ASP.NET Web API Project option. This option adds files to your React template so that it can be hooked up with the ASP.NET Core project, if an ASP.NET Core project is added.
7. Choose Create, and then wait for Visual Studio to create the
   project.

Please note that creation of the React project takes a moment because the create-react-app command that runs at this time also runs the npm install command.

Comment: I got your point, i have added required details from MSDN article. Thanks.